# Custom field created via REST API for Lead object not visible in add lead form

Tags: rest-api, custom-field, leads

I created a custom field through this tooling REST API
`/services/data/v54.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField`
The API call succeed and I could see the custom fields under Setup > Object Manager > Lead.

Try to add a lead using this REST API
`/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/Lead`
It says the fields does not exist. even though I can see that field in object manager. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `POST` `/services/data/v54.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField` and below request body I created the field test2__c

> {
> "FullName": "Lead.test2__c",
> "Metadata": {
> "label": "test",
> "description": "my new test field",
> "required": false,
> "externalId": false,
> "type": "Text",
> "length": 32
> }
> }

When I tried POST with `/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/Lead` it gave me same error

> {
> "Salutation": "Mr.",
> "FirstName": "STACK",
> "LastName": "EXAMPLE",
> "test2__c": "hey",
> "Company": "Samosa"}

After setting up FLS for this test2__c to editable for my profile(I did this via UI but based on [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/208317/80089), looks like this can be done via REST API), I was able to insert the lead record.

Comment: Thanks Swetha, for your response, I will try this out