# Create profile tooling API giving INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api, custom-field, tooling-api

I created a CustomField using the tooling API: POST "tooling/sobjects/CustomField"
But it creates a custom field without the permissions on "Field-Level Security for Profile"
As I understood right I need to set the fieldPermissions on this custom field.

I'm trying to do this:
POST to "tooling/sobjects/Profile/"
With this payload.

```
{
    "Metadata":{    
        "fieldPermissions": [
            {
                "editable": false,
                "field": "Contact.MyCustom__c",
                "hidden": false,
                "readable": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "FullName" : "Contact.MyCustom__c"
}
```

And I'm getting the error "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY"
What I'm missing from this? Should I use other resource to set this permission?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use the Tooling API to update field level security on Profiles and PermissionSets?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208307/is-it-possible-to-use-the-tooling-api-to-update-field-level-security-on-profiles)

Comment: Yes, thanks. It worked.